# Subset the remaining of a dataframe using another subset

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a sample dataset. I've created a subset of the original data frame using some condition. Now I need to extract the remaining contents of the original sample data frame, except the subset created. How can I do this?

```
data("mtcars")
fulldf <- mtcars
subdf <- subset.data.frame(fulldf, subset = fulldf$disp < 100)
restdf <- subset.data.frame(fulldf, subset = <fulldf without subdf>)
```

There are a lot of questions on subsetting data frames in R, but I couldn't find one that satisfied my requirement. 
Also the final solution need not necessarily be using `subset.data.frame`. Any method/package will do.

Comment: There is a nice way using `setdiff` from `dplyr`: `dplyr::setdiff(fulldf, subdf)`

Comment: Thank you markus! This did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to assign the logical condition in `base R` to an object identifier and then negate (`!`)

```
i1 <- fulldf$disp < 100
subdf <- subset.data.frame(fulldf, subset = i1)
restdf <- subset.data.frame(fulldf, subset = !i1)
```

---

Also another option is to create a `list` of two datasets with `split`

```
lst1 <- split(fulldf, i1)
```

---

If the 'subdf' is creating with multiple conditions (not clear though), one option is to add a sequence variable in the data and then subset with `%in%`

```
fulldf$ind <- seq_len(nrow(fulldf))
```

then after the 'subdf' step

```
restdf <- subset(fulldf, !ind %in% subdf$ind)
```

and remove the 'ind' columns

```
restdf$ind <- NULL
subdf$ind <- NULL
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a good solution but unfortunately I'm creating the `subdf` using multiple conditions and can't store it in one variable.

Comment: @snair1591 Wouldn't the end output would be a logical vector?

Comment: I'm using `rbind` to create my `subd` through multiple conditions, if that helps.

Comment: @snair1591  I added another `base R` method.  It can be also done by creating a condition with `row.names`, but I think the `rbind` and other methods might have changed changed the row names during the process

Comment: @snair1591 It could be solved easily with packages, but I would only use external dependency if there is no other choice/efficiency etc.